# Access denied exception when using AnonymousPipeClientStream on Linux/Mono

Tags: c#, linux, mono

The below example runs fine on a Windows environment, but crashes with `UnauthorizedAccessException` when creating the `AnonymousPipeClientStream` object under Linux/Mono. Is there anything obvious I might be missing when creating client pipes in child processes under Linux/Mono?

```cs
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO.Pipes;
using System.Reflection;
using System.IO;
using System;

namespace pipetest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            if (args.Length > 0)
            {
                // client
                using var pipeClient = new AnonymousPipeClientStream(
                    PipeDirection.Out,
                    args[0]);
                using var pipeReader = new StreamReader(pipeClient);
                Console.WriteLine(args[0]);
            }
            else
            {
                // server
                using var pipeServer = new AnonymousPipeServerStream(
                    PipeDirection.In,
                    HandleInheritability.Inheritable);
                var setupInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
                setupInfo.FileName = Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location;
                setupInfo.Arguments = pipeServer.GetClientHandleAsString();
                setupInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
                setupInfo.WorkingDirectory = Environment.CurrentDirectory;
                var process = Process.Start(setupInfo);
                pipeServer.DisposeLocalCopyOfClientHandle();
                process.WaitForExit();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the full stack-trace:

```
Unhandled Exception:
System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path is denied. ---> System.IO.IOException: Bad file descriptor
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at System.IO.Pipes.PipeStream.CheckPipeCall (System.Int32 result) [0x00027] in <f6c405b973804b5c804e7e759353765f>:0 
  at System.IO.Pipes.PipeStream.ValidateHandleIsPipe (Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles.SafePipeHandle safePipeHandle) [0x00011] in <f6c405b973804b5c804e7e759353765f>:0 
  at System.IO.Pipes.AnonymousPipeClientStream.Init (System.IO.Pipes.PipeDirection direction, Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles.SafePipeHandle safePipeHandle) [0x00000] in <f6c405b973804b5c804e7e759353765f>:0 
  at System.IO.Pipes.AnonymousPipeClientStream..ctor (System.IO.Pipes.PipeDirection direction, System.String pipeHandleAsString) [0x00067] in <f6c405b973804b5c804e7e759353765f>:0 
  at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.IO.Pipes.AnonymousPipeClientStream..ctor(System.IO.Pipes.PipeDirection,string)
  at pipetest.Program.Main (System.String[] args) [0x0000b] in <c8e4903c8b0849deb2fe2cc770dcaf3a>:0
```

Comment: I saw this line above the class: `[System.MonoTODO("Anonymous pipes are not working even on win32, due to some access authorization issue")]`

Comment: Docs for the comment by @shingo http://docs.go-mono.com/monodoc.ashx?link=T%3ASystem.IO.Pipes.AnonymousPipeServerStream

Comment: Wow, it seems hard to believe that the Mono implementation survived for so long without at least a bare-bones implementation of basic parent/child process communication. I cannot find any obvious workaround online so will keep question open for suggestions.

Comment: https://halfblood.pro/the-end-of-mono/ Even if you keep it open, there isn't likely to be any future activities. Mono project never intended to cover everything from .NET Framework. It survived because of its coverage of all the other important APIs (like Linux and mobile) but now .NET Core takes the burdens over.